# In grammar, can particle be placed in mid position?

Tags: adverb-placement

Initial: Up he goes.
Final: He goes up.
Mid: He up goes. It seems like there's no rule which says not.

Comment: Mid position sounds a bit archaic and literary to me.

Comment: "A bit archaic"?  "Whether he be dead or alive" is a bit archaic. "He up goes" just sounds utterly bizarre.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The rule concerns word order. No: you can't say *"He up goes". Incidentally, "up" is a preposition functioning as complement of "goes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He up goes.

No, absolutely wrong.  You might get away with it in a poem, where word order is more flexible.

Comment: But in etymology there are many cases. prepare, protect, company, withstanding.

Comment: I think it is archaic.

Comment: Yes, there are some words with prepositions fused onto the front, like "withstand", "upstanding", "outstanding".  But that's a slightly different matter.  There is no space between the two words.  They are inseparable.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb#Analogy_to_English

Comment: @rjpond I think I can use it because I love poetry.